# What library to use for Camera Native Android

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I have the following code...

gl_game.cpp

```
#include <camera/Camera.h>
....
using namespace android;
LOGI("Number of cameras are... %d", Camera::getNumberOfCameras());
```

and the Android.mk...

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AOSP/frameworks/av/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AOSP/frameworks/native/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AOSP/system/core/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../AOSP/hardware/libhardware/include
```

When I try to compile I see a linker error...

```
error: undefined reference to 'android::Camera::getNumberOfCameras()'
```

I am assuming this is because I never added the .so containing Camera.cpp to my LOCAL_LDLIBS but I cannot find the proper .so file to add to the linker. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did, I think the problem here is that the .so file implementation is Manufacturer specific. Because I am just testing and haven't made it that far yet I used a rooted emulator to grab the .so off of the emulator device itself...

```
adb pull /system/lib/libcamera_client.so ../project/jni/lib/
```

Then added the following to my Android.mk....

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcam
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libcamera_client.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
...
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcam
```

now I see...

> I/libgl2jni(  843): Number of cameras are... 0

Which is what I would expect from an emulator...

Same file also worked on my ASUS tablet...

> I/libgl2jni( 8175): Number of cameras are... 2

Comment: Awesome! :D Can this be done without pulling in the SO from a device or emulator? 

How does the OpenCV build do it? (I'm reading through it but yet to understand how they do it.)

Comment: I am not sure about that I was working on it for a bit but then I ran into some issues with projection. Good luck and feel free to add to the answer!